# Problema con el "encoding": Caracteres correctamente almacenados en MySQL aparecen "raros" en Java

Tags: java, mysql

Estimados, tengo un pequeño problema con una aplicación Java que estoy escribiendo.

Es una aplicación que se conecta vía JDBC a MySQL. Al guardar los registros, los caractéres se guardan correctamente (si escribo "México" en un cuadro JText y lo envío a la base de datos, se guarda como "México"); pero al leerlos de regreso usando el método `ResultSet.getString()` los caractéres "especiales" (acentos y "ñ") aparecen mal ("México" se lee como "M��xico").

Creo que es algo que tiene que ver con el "encoding" de los caractéres, pero no sé específicamente qué es.. La base de datos MySQL utiliza el encoding `utf8_spanish_ci`, y la función `Charset.defaultCharset()` devuelve `UTF-8`.

Mi pregunta específica es, entonces: **¿Cómo lograr que las cadenas leídas de MySQL que contienen caractéres especiales (que fueron correctamente almacenadas) se muestren correctamente en la aplicación Java?**

---

### Actualización (solución parcial):

Después de buscar un rato más, encontré [esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730359/problems-reading-writing-utf-8-data-in-mysql-from-java-using-jdbc-connector-5-1) que me ayudaron. Específicamente, lo que dice es que al momento de abrir la conexión hay que especificar el set de caractéres que se usará; en mi caso:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbName 
           + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8_spanish_ci", 
    user, pass);
```

Sin embargo, sólo soluciona *parcialmente* el problema:

Al leer datos de campos `VARCHAR` los caractéres especiales se leen correctamente. Sin embargo, al leer de campos `JSON`, los valores que tienen caracteres especiales se siguen mostrando "raros".

---

### Actualización (final):

El problema tiene que ver con el *encoding* que MySQL usa para guardar los datos JSON; La respuesta más abajo ilustra el procedimiento que seguí para solucionarlo.

Comment: si has solucionado el problema, puedes publicar la solución en una respuesta aparte, así se podrá cerrar la pregunta, con el check verde.

Comment: @Webserveis la solución es "parcial"... Aún no logro solucionar del todo el problema (tal como menciono en la actualización)

Comment: @Barranka eliminé mi respuesta, al parecer tienes especificado el set de caracteres como utf-8, es así???

Comment: Efectivamente. Además, está raro que el problema persiste sólo en los datos que están en columnas JSON

Comment: @Webserveis Acabo de publicar la solución que implementé (no la de la actualización a la pregunta, que era sólo una precisión en el problema).

Comment: @Elenasys Encontré el problema con la codificación: Resulta que MySQL codifica las cadenas JSON a `utf8mb4`, por lo que a la hora de leer `utf8_spanish` la cosa no funcionaba bien. Publiqué una respuesta al respecto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Después de rascarle un rato más al problema, encontré esta referencia en el manual de usuario de MySQL:

> MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_bin` collation. Strings in other character set are converted to `utf8mb4` as necessary.

Así que, sin importar la codificación de caracteres que yo use, MySQL automáticamente convierte la cadena JSON a `utf8mb4`... lo cual no es mayor problema al guardar, pero sí al leer de regreso :(

Mi solución (y sospecho que no es la mejor), fue la siguiente: Escribir, dentro de la consulta, la conversión a la codificación requerida. Algo así como esto:

```
strSQL = "select convert(cast(a.json_data as char) using 'utf8') as json_data "
       + "from mi_tabla "
       + "where id = ?";
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL)) {
    /*
       Mi código para leer la tabla
     */
}
```

Con este "ajuste", los datos se leen perfectamente (con todos los caracteres acentuados correctos).

Supongo que puede haber una forma más sencilla de solucionar este problema, pero hasta ahora esta solución me ha servido.

Comment: muy buena contribución, gracias!